# Detecting caller ID with TAPI c#

Tags: c#, telephony, modem, tapi, caller-id

At my workplace, I need an application that allows me to see the caller's number when I call a landline and retrieve the information from the database. We currently use an application that does this, but it works with a subscription system and does not work exactly as we want. I hope to design such an application in c#. I did some research and saw that I had 2 options to detect caller ID. 1. Connecting to the modem via serial port and receiving caller ID via AT commands. 2. Using TAPI.

It seems much easier to connect to the modem via serial port, but there is a problem. The modem does not appear in the device manager or phone and moodem settings. (There is [this](https://kb.sambapos.com/en/3-6-caller-id-setup-and-configurations/) device connected to the computer)
So I decided to use Julmar's ATAPI.

Do I need additional hardware to make this application using TAPI?

How do I detect the modem (or the device in the link) with TAPI? Does it do it automatically?